# Which is preferred "Would you" or "Will you wait for me"?

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness

Which is the correct sentence:

> **Will** you wait for me?

or

> **Would** you wait for me?

*would* sounds pretty polite.

Comment: Please see [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). Especially this: **You might wait 24 to 48 hours to give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both polite enough, in that sense there is no difference.

The difference in meaning is between the Future Indefinite ("*will* you") and subjunctive mood ("*would* you wait") is that in the former case the necessity for waiting is known to the speaker and the party whom the speaker is asking, whereas the latter ("*would*") suggests that the need for waiting is yet not certain, or even hypothetical.

Comment: Sometimes *would* is used for deference. I think in that case it is short for a longer phrase like "If it pleases you, would you...?" (which is grammatically in the subjunctive even though the situation would normally require the indicative).

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are "correct."

*Would* does indicate politeness/deference, and *will* can be used in "not certain" or "hypothetical" situations:

Will you wait for me if I asked you nice(ly)?

Would you wait for me if I asked you nice(ly)?

Here, *would* shows more deference ( ~= politeness). While, *will*, as usual when talking about future time, talks about the ***current resolve*** of the--in this case--the person being asked, to carry out a future action. It is neutral as far as deference/politeness.

As for your sentences, then, use *would* to be more polite/deferential.

Answer (score 0):

'Would you wait for me?' is you trying to figure out if they'd do it.

'Will you wait for me?' is asking them to do it.